# two instance of custom classloader load the same class, but the class not equal

Tags: java, classloader

i used two instance of custom classloader to load the class, but their hashCode not equal.

```
public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader{

    private String mLibPath;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        MyClassLoader classLoader1 = new MyClassLoader("/Users/kk/Downloads");
        MyClassLoader classLoader2 = new MyClassLoader("/Users/kk/Downloads");
        Class<?> c1 = classLoader1.loadClass("loader.DemoObj");
        Class<?> c2 = classLoader2.loadClass("loader.DemoObj");
        System.out.println(c1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(c2.hashCode());

    }

    public MyClassLoader(String path){
        mLibPath = path;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String fileName = getFileName(name);
        File file = new File(mLibPath,fileName);
        try {
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int len=0;
            try{
                while((len = is.read()) != -1){
                    bos.write(len);
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            is.close();
            bos.close();

            return defineClass(name, data, 0, data.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.findClass(name);



    }

    private String getFileName(String name){
        name = name.replace(".","/");
        return name+".class";
    }


}
```

classLoader1 and classLoader2 are both invoke loadClass("loader.DemoObj")，they should invoke findLoadedClass() to check whether the cache have the Class of loader.DemoObj. The Code above should return two same number，but my code returns different.

```
1846274136
1639705018
```

Comment: Hi, I see that you are new here.  The short answer is "because they are different classes" -- that is how custom classloaders work.  See https://coderanch.com/t/380416/java/Loading-class-class-loader-ClassCastException.  Were you expecting two different classloaders to produce the same Class?  The only way you should expect the same Class is when both classloaders delegate to the system classloader.

Comment: Congratulations for finding one of the worst ways to read from an `InputStream` into a `byte[]` array. But anyway, these two class loader instances are like name spaces containing different classes. Why are you creating two of them, when you want the behavior of exactly one?